# WinForms TableLayoutPanel ScrollToControl method having no effect

Tags: winforms

The `ScrollToControl` method of the TableLayoutPanel is having no effect. What are the prerequisites for it to work?

Here are the settings:

```
this.RowCount = 0;
this.AutoScroll = true;
this.AutoSize = true; 
this.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
this.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
```

Here is the code that tries to scroll  the newly appended control into view, in my class that derives from `TableLayoutPanel`:

```
var ctrl = AppendNewUserControl(data);   
//ctrl.Select();                       // tried selecting first, no luck
//this.ScrollControlIntoView(ctrl);    // tried scrolling into view first, no luck
this.ScrollToControl(ctrl);
```

Here is the code that creates and appends the control to the TableLayoutPanel's Controls collection:

```
private MyUserControl AppendNewUserControl(customDataObject item)
{
    var uc = new MyUserControl(MyBindingSource, item);
    uc.Name = "uc" + new Guid().ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(uc);
    return uc;
}
```

Comment: [ScrollableControl.SetDisplayRectLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.setdisplayrectlocation) ([`ScrollToControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrolltocontrol) returns a `Point`)

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks for that. I had just found this, which is also not working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Well, that's not the link to the method I posted :)

Comment: @Jimi: Right, it's a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an alternative to a TableLayoutPanel and found my way to [IContainerControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ContainerControl__ctor) interface.

Implementing the interface gives the desired functionality.